# Tikz task diagram (alignment and arrows)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to create a diagram like this in LaTeX:

[image: original]

This is what I have so far using the [assignment structure from texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/):

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm,start chain=going below]
\node[punktchain, join] (client) {$Client$};
\node[punktchain, join] (server) {$Job\ server$};
\node[punktchain, join] (worker1) {$Worker_1$};
\node[punktchain, join] (worker2) {$Worker_2$};
\node[punktchain, join] (worker3) {$Worker_3$};
\node[punktchain, join] (worker4) {$Worker_4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But now I'm stuck. I don't know how to use double-sided arrows and I can't place the workers next to each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think a chain is the correct type for your diagram. You can however position the nodes manually. The `positioning` library provides some advanced positioning keys.

Please also don't misuse mathmode to get italic text. Use `\textit` for that. You can use math supscript for the index only or use `\textsubscript` (needs to [`fixltx2e`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=5pt,node distance=.8cm]
\node [draw](client) {\textit{Client}};
\node [draw,below=of client] (server) {\textit{Job server}};
\node [inner sep=0pt,below=of server] (aux) {\strut};
\node [draw,left=.4cm of aux] (worker2) {\textit{Worker$_2$}};
\node [draw,right=.4cm of aux] (worker3) {\textit{Worker$_3$}};
\node [draw,left=of worker2] (worker1) {\textit{Worker$_1$}};
\node [draw,right=of worker3] (worker4) {\textit{Worker$_4$}};
\draw [<->] (client) -- (server);
\foreach \n in {1,...,4}
   \draw [<->] (server) -- (worker\n.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I also didn't knew about the \textit. Thanks!